# OPENSSL_CONF and diffs between dotnet run vs dotnet myall.dll in .net core 6 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sql-server, .net-core

I need to make SQL connections to an old SQL Server 2012 instance running on Windows Server 2012. I realize these products are already or soon to be EOL, but it is what it is and I have no control to upgrade.  With .net core 3.1 on CentOS 8 we had no problems. But we recently moved to Ubuntu 20.04 and .net core 6 and it seems that the default SSL policy on 20.04 is incompatible with the older ciphers SQL Server 2012 is using - so I made a new policy and pointed at it by setting the OPENSSL_CONF environment variable.  Here's where it gets weird:

1. I have several .NET clients that need to connect to that database.  One is just a simple CLI program.  This one works fine if I invoke it with `dotnet run`. Oddly, if I invoke it with `dotnet app.dll` it does not work - i.e. I get a SSL error connecting to the database just like it was doing before I added the new policy via the environment variable.
2. Another app that needs to connect is a kestrel based web app. Same deal on it - if I do `dotnet app.dll` it works but continues to throw the SSL exception when connecting to that database - but if I do `dotnet run` it works. Unfortunately, this app also needs to bind to port 443 which requires `setcap` - and it appears that "dotnet run" must use some other application other than `/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet` to launch - because when I do `dotnet run` on this project I get permission denied trying to bind the port even though I did `setcap cap_net_bind_service=+eip /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet`.  The app works and connects to the DB fine if I run it on a non privileged port and invoke it with `dotnet run`.

I will probably end up filing an issue or two against this, but thought I would ask here first.  Seems to be two issues really:

1. Why does launching via `dotnet myapp.dll` totally ignore the OPENSSL_CONF environment variable despite it being set, and showing up if i do `Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OPENSSL_CONF")}");`?
2. When using `dotnet run` to launch what exes do you need to give `setcap` capabilities to above and beyond `/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet` on Ubuntu 20.04?

Alternatively, I guess while waiting, I may try latest Alma and see how if it has the same or different problems.

Comment: There isn't and never has been a SQL Server **2012 R2** version - just **2012** - fixed. SQL Server **2008 R2** was the only "R2" version ever.

Comment: At a best guess they are actually using Windows Server 2012 R2 (as 2012 isn't supported anymore) and SQL Server 2012, and put the R2 in the wrong place, @marc_s . Though they do explicitly acknowledge they are using unsupported software, which Windows Server 2012 is, as well as soon to be, which SQL Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2 fall into.

Comment: Sorry - i got a little carried away with typing the R2 - it's SQL 2012 build 11.0.7507 not that it matters.